# Microsoft VBScript runtime error 800a0034

Tags: vbscript

When I save the image, show this message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0034' 
Bad file name or number 
/asp/upload2_assinaturas.asp, line 232
```

and in the line 232 has:

```vb
Dim TextStream : Set TextStream = FS.CreateTextFile(FileName)
```

Value Filename:

```vb
FileName = (SeparateField (Head, "filename =", ";")) 'ltrim
```

And the funtion save:

```vb
Function SaveBinaryData(FileName, ByteArray) 
  Dim FS : Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
  Dim TextStream : Set TextStream = FS.CreateTextFile(FileName) 
  TextStream.Write BinaryToString(ByteArray) 
  TextStream.Close 
  'response.write(FileName & "," & ByteArray) 
  'response.end 
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of `FileName`?

Comment: The error says that there's a problem related to what's going on in line 232. That either means that the variable `FS` has a problem, or the variable `FileName` has a problem. It is most likely, from the error message, that the variable `FileName` has a problem. If you display the value of `FileName` (e.g., `MsgBox(FileName,0)`, what does it show?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. You can edit your existing question and add the code there.

Comment: _How_ you are deriving the file name is _irrelevant_. What is needed here is to show what the _result_ of that derivation is - if that result has characters that are invalid in a file name, it will cause any call that interacts with the file system to throw an error. **You need to show us the *actual* file name that you are attempting to create with the call in line 232**.

Comment: the name is : "assinatura.jpg"